# Angular 2.3 / Zone.js 0.7.2: Some components broken

Tags: angular

I have an application using Angular 2.2.4, with zone.js version defined as `^0.6.25` in `package.json`. I tried to update to Angular 2.3 and `zone.js` `^0.7.2`, and found that some components broke with exception message “Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined”. Surprisingly, the broken components do not very different things than other components that still do work – they use templates in separate files, use an API service via Rx.js etc., but obviously, there must be some reason why these components fail reproducably.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242638/4715679) on SO pointed out that the problem might be related to the zone.js version used, so I downgraded to the previous 0.6.25 and found that everything works flawlessly (or rather least everything which is covered by e2e tests, which is most of the application).

Any hints for solving the problem? If not: should it be safe to stick with the zone.js `0.6.x`, or will I run into problems with Angular2 sooner or later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I did not find the cause of the problem, I tested Angular 2.4.1 with zone.js 0.7.4, and this worked perfectly.

Comment: Has anyone tested with Angular 2.4.2 and zone.js 0.7.4 I am getting the following issues when trying to run phantomjs tests:

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Missing: SyncTestZoneSpec
  at webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:43:0 <- karma.entry.js:7147
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.329 secs / 0 secs

Answer (score 1):

Here is the cause of the [bug](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/554). It happens ;)

Comment: Not sure if it’s the same cause, as in the ticket you mention, the reporter states that 0.7.3 broke what worked in 0.7.2, whereas in my case, it didn’t with 0.7.2.